# Generate URL in Grails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, grails

I need to pass a correct URL to a javascript function in one of my GSPs.  I don't want to just hard code it just in case the mappings for that URL ever change.

I know in Rails I would use the url_for method such as:

```
<%= url_for :controller => 'something', :action => 'edit', :id => 3 %>
```

How would I do this in Grails?  I can't seem to find a GSP tag or anything that would return a properly formatted URL given the controller, action, id, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use createLink, see http://grails.org/doc/1.2/ref/Tags/createLink.html

Comment: the link has 404'ed. http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html should be valid ad eternum, since it doesn't reference a specific version.